# Display Category Thumbnail and links in Woo commerce

Tags: post-thumbnails, woocommerce-offtopic, terms

I would like to display my categories with a thumbnail in woocommerce. I am able to  list the child terms as a link but i would like to add additional content. I have added the code below in which I use to display the child terms for "product_cat" as a link on my template home-page.php. But I would also like to add the category image. I would really appreciate the help THANKS.

```
<?php

$taxonomyName = "product_cat";
//This gets top layer terms only.  This is done by setting parent to 0.  
$parent_terms = get_terms($taxonomyName, array('parent' => 0, 'orderby' => 'slug', 'hide_empty' => false));   
echo '<ul>';
foreach ($parent_terms as $pterm) {
    //Get the Child terms
    $terms = get_terms($taxonomyName, array('parent' => $pterm->term_id, 'orderby' => 'slug', 'hide_empty' => false));
    foreach ($terms as $term) {

        echo '<li><a href="' . get_term_link( $term->name, $taxonomyName ) . '">' . $term->name . '</a></li>';  
    }
}
echo '</ul>';


?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have did some customization. This will help you show parent and child category images. You can later customize this code as per your requirements.

```
    $taxonomyName = "product_cat";
//This gets top layer terms only.  This is done by setting parent to 0.  
    $parent_terms = get_terms($taxonomyName, array('parent' => 0, 'orderby' => 'slug', 'hide_empty' => false));

    echo '<ul>';
    foreach ($parent_terms as $pterm) {

        //show parent categories
        echo '<li><a href="' . get_term_link($pterm->name, $taxonomyName) . '">' . $pterm->name . '</a></li>';

        $thumbnail_id = get_woocommerce_term_meta($pterm->term_id, 'thumbnail_id', true);
        // get the image URL for parent category
        $image = wp_get_attachment_url($thumbnail_id);
        // print the IMG HTML for parent category
        echo "<img src='{$image}' alt='' width='400' height='400' />";

        //Get the Child terms
        $terms = get_terms($taxonomyName, array('parent' => $pterm->term_id, 'orderby' => 'slug', 'hide_empty' => false));
        foreach ($terms as $term) {

            echo '<li><a href="' . get_term_link($term->name, $taxonomyName) . '">' . $term->name . '</a></li>';
            $thumbnail_id = get_woocommerce_term_meta($pterm->term_id, 'thumbnail_id', true);
            // get the image URL for child category
            $image = wp_get_attachment_url($thumbnail_id);
            // print the IMG HTML for child category
            echo "<img src='{$image}' alt='' width='400' height='400' />";
        }
    }
    echo '</ul>';
```

Let me know if it fulfills your requirement.

Answer (score 4):

Hello @Wisdmlabs Thank you for your help. I have found this to work very well incase anyone else is wondering how to do so.

```
$taxonomyName = "product_cat";
$prod_categories = get_terms($taxonomyName, array(
    'orderby'=> 'name',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'hide_empty' => 1
));  

foreach( $prod_categories as $prod_cat ) :
    if ( $prod_cat->parent != 0 )
        continue;
    $cat_thumb_id = get_woocommerce_term_meta( $prod_cat->term_id, 'thumbnail_id', true );
    $cat_thumb_url = wp_get_attachment_thumb_url( $cat_thumb_id );
    $term_link = get_term_link( $prod_cat, 'product_cat' );
    ?>

    <img  src="<?php echo $cat_thumb_url; ?>" alt="" /> 
    <a class="button" href="<?php echo $term_link; ?>"> <?php echo $prod_cat->name; ?> </a> 
    <?php endforeach; 
wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

To further optimize the @Wisdmlabs's answer above, replace this line

```
$cat_thumb_url = wp_get_attachment_thumb_url( $cat_thumb_id );
```

with

```
$cat_thumb_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $cat_thumb_id, 'thumbnail-size' )[0]; // Change to desired 'thumbnail-size'
```

This way the images are cropped to suitable size on the server to reduce bandwidth load.